# Is there a way to zoom before a specified page break when converting an excel sheet to PDF in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am working on a project to automate payroll and have developed a couple of Macros already, but am having trouble in the last step. I am copying data from one workbook to another, so that the timecard sheet is attached to the invoice sheet. I am then automating creating PDFs and when I create the PDFs, they shrink to fit the larger page that I have attached. I have inserted a manual page break to create two separate pages in my PDF, but the PDF is still shrinking the first page and not fitting it to the full page. Is there a way to zoom before the page break, so that the first page fits the full PDF size?

I have tried manually changing the PDF formatting, changing the print preview etc.

```
Sub Excel_to_PDF()


     Dim Path As String
     Dim filename As String
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim nm As String



     For Each ws In Worksheets

     If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ws.Select
        nm = ws.Name
        ActiveSheet.Rows(44).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:="C:\Users\rober\Desktop\Invoices\" & nm & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("K6").Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
        Next ws

        Dim ZoomRng As Range
        Set ZoomRng = Range("A1:M43")
        ZoomRng.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True

End Sub
```

I want the PDF to be split between two pages. The first page before line 44, and the second page after. That is not a problem. This Macro works for that. What I need is for the sheet before line 44 to be zoomed and not scaled to fit with the same dimensions as the second sheet. The first sheet goes from A1:L43, and the second sheet goes from A50:AC110. The first sheet gets shrunk because of this, and I want it zoomed in on.

Comment: A single PDF export must have the same enlargement/reduction for all pages on a worksheet. You'll probably need to export two PDFs and then merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think the zoom was in the wrong place.

```
Sub Excel_to_PDF()


     Dim Path As String
     Dim filename As String
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim nm As String



     For Each ws In Worksheets

      If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ws.Select
        nm = ws.Name

        Dim ZoomRng As Range
        Set ZoomRng = Range("A1:M43")
        ZoomRng.Select
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = True

        ActiveSheet.Rows(44).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:="C:\Users\rober\Desktop\Invoices\" & nm & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("K6").Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
       End If
      Next ws

End Sub
```